# Writing to Core Data from a secondary thread

Tags: multithreading, uitableview, core-data, asynchronous, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an HTTP call to a URL, which returns my data in JSON format, I parse it, then I have to load it in my Core Data context.

Now I am doing it (parsing - entities creation - commit) on the main thread, by using GCD (grand central dispatch) to dispatch a block on the main queue.
The http call is asynchronous, so it's ok, but the db loading is not, so it freezes my user interface: a UITableView backed by a NSFetchedResultsController.

What I'd like to do, is making these last tasks on a secondary thread, but don't know how!

I heard something about creating a second context, using that on the secondary thread, then trash it and "refresh" the "main" context, don't know how to explain.
Maybe is there a wwdc ed. video on this argument, too? I can't find valid documentation.

Can you help me, loading data in asynchronous way, so my table never stop scrolling?

Comment: I just responded to a similar question here. It should have everything you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540801/coredata-and-threads-gcd/7545514#7545514

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule: One context for one thread. Create new context in your not main queue and work with it.

Add observer for this context:
`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(<#Selector name#>)
                                      name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                      object:<#A managed object context#>];`

After your parser is done and objects in context, save that context which will kick out notification. In main queue, catch this notification and on main queue context call `- (void)mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification`.

Comment: That solution does not work, can you help me out with a little more details please? The notification arrives, but it still freezes my gui for a few seconds

Comment: just freezes for a few seconds during mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

Comment: Well, this is how it should be done. I would try to find solution in another question...