# CoreData: error: NULL _cd_rawData but the object is not being turned into a fault

Tags: iphone, core-data

I occasionally get this error when saving to core data. I cannot manage to recreate it.

Does anyone have any experience with this error;

```
CoreData: error: NULL _cd_rawData but the object is not being turned into a fault
```

?

Comment: Are you using multi threading?
If yes, make sure that saving context should be done on Main Thread

Comment: Yes I am. But im working in another context and merge the changes in the main thread.

Comment: Hi, can anyone explain why this error only happens occasionally?

Comment: As a general approach to learning more about the topic and ways to prevent such issues I would recommend the following Stanford lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whF63GTaW1w

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After going to several post, this had a better answer https://web.archive.org/web/20150215081345/http://www.cocoabuilder.com:80/archive/cocoa/311615-weird-core-data-crash.html

Comment: Link is not active anymore, solution not visible!

Comment: Answer edited to put an active link to the same content.

Answer (score 57):

## Reason:

This happens when the object's context does not belong to the current thread.  One of many ways that mistake can manifest itself.

## Debug:

When the crash occurs do the following:

1. Check the thread in which the crash occured (Xcode > Debug Navigator)
2. On the console print, the concurrency type of the `NSManagedObjectContext`
3. If the concurrency type is `mainQueueConcurrencyType` then it needs to be on the main thread otherwise on the background threads.

### Console command to check concurrency type:

```
p context.concurrencyType
```

In the sample command above the `NSManagedObjectContext` was stored in the variable `context`

### Console Output:

```
(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType) $R4 = mainQueueConcurrencyType
```

Comment: Yes this was exactly my case. This error is basically because of accessing the main MOC from the background thread.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: If you need to access the database from a background thread, use that thread to create a new MOC, then use it to create, query, mutate, save, etc. [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) was very helpful for my app.

Comment: In my case, It was already on the background thread but the frequent switching from the backgrounf thread to main thread causes this error and a crash

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem when I tried to read (access) data from a Coredata Store in other thread (not main).

You can solve this problem by following this suggestion from this link:
[Core Data and threads / Grand Central Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540801/core-data-and-threads-grand-central-dispatch)

Comment: That thread has 6 answers; can you be more specific about what you found in that thread that was helpful?