# Multiple Managed Object Context

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have seen many times people use many managedObjectContext, but aside from when using the Undo manager, what is the real reason for using multipleManagedObjectContext? Why can it be useful to use more than one? Could you please show a few examples?

Answer (score 1):

Managed object contexts are not thread safe so if you ever need to do any kind of background work with your Coredata objects (i.e. a long running import/export function without blocking the main UI) you will want to do that on a background thread.

In these cases you will need to create a new managed object context on the background thread, iterate through your coredata operation and then notify the main context of your changes.

You can find an example of how this could work here [Core Data and threads / Grand Central Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540801/core-data-and-threads-grand-central-dispatch/7545514#7545514)

Comment: The answer is quite right, but NSManagedObjectContexts are indeed thread safe, and having more context for not blocking UI has imho nothing to do with threads safety. In this case, when more context need to be updated, the object to lock or synchronize is the persistence store coordinator.

Comment: Sorry but your comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What does UI performance and thread safety has to do with a background work.

Comment: If you're performing long running tasks in the main thread you are blocking the UI and your app will appear non-responsive to the user, hence the interest in doing some of this work in the background.

Comment: This is clear, and well known, and I totally agree to you. The point is that this matter has nothing to do with thread safety, but only with performance.

Comment: So why don't you have a go answering the OPs question?